# "invalid use of pipe placeholder" with base R pipe inside dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Why is this command with base R pipe and placeholder within `dplyr::mutate` returning an error message ?

```r
library(dplyr)
iris[,-5] |> mutate(Row_sum = apply(X = _, 1, function(x) sum(x)))

#> Error in mutate(iris[, -5], Row_sum = apply(X = "_", 1, function(x) sum(x))) : 
#> invalid use of pipe placeholder
```

Works fine outside mutate :

```r
iris[,-5] |> apply(X = _, 1, function(x) sum(x))

#>   [1] 10.2  9.5  9.4  9.4 10.2 11.4  9.7 10.1  8.9  9.6 10.8 10.0  9.3  8.5 11.2
#>  [16] 12.0 11.0 10.3 11.5 10.7 10.7 10.7  9.4 10.6 10.3  9.8 10.4 10.4 10.2  9.7
#>  [31]  (...)
```

Works fine inside mutate with magrittr pipe

```r
iris[,-5] %>% mutate(Row_sum = apply(X = ., 1, function(x) sum(x))) %>% head

#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Row_sum
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    10.2
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     9.5
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     9.4
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     9.4
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    10.2
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    11.4
```

Comment: The row sums is just for the reprex... My original function was more like `all(is.na(x))`. But my main aim is just to understand how this new pipe works. So if I understand well, the answer to my question is : "because base R pipe placeholder does not work in nested functions while magrittr pipe placeholder does." Did I understood correctly ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you can't use the `_` with `|>` when using nested function calls. For example the first one works, the second does not

```
5 |> log()
# [1] 1.609438
5 |> log(exp(_))
# Error in log(5, exp("_")) : invalid use of pipe placeholder
```

Note that `|>` with `_` is a bit different than `%>%` with `.` in this case. If you used `.` with `%>%` as part of an expression, the full piped object was still passed as the first parameter to the function. So you essentially included it twice. This will never happen with `|>` and `_`. For example

```
iris %>% split(.$Species)
```

works because it's the same as

```
split(iris, iris$Species)
```

Note that the iris basically gets included twice. But this does not work with the new pipe operator

```
iris |> split(_$Species)
# Error in split(iris, "_"$Species) : invalid use of pipe placeholder
```

because again it's basically a nested function call (the `$` counts as a function call). That's one of the reason they simultaneously updated `split` to use a formula now as well. So this will work

```
iris |> split(~Species)
```

If you just want to add a row sum without the fifth column, you can do

```
iris |>
    mutate(Row_sums=rowSums(across(-5)))
# or
iris[, -5]|>
    mutate(Row_sums=rowSums(across(everything())))
```

Comment: I did understood correctly with your first comment ;-) Thanks for the very clear answer and for the solution with across. Maybe you could add a third example using apply which was necessary in my real life use case. For example this works fine : `iris[,-5] |> mutate(SD = apply(across(everything()), 1, sd))`

Comment: @Gilles I strongly suggest avoiding the use of `apply` with a data.frame it can cause a lot of problems if you have mixed data types because it coerces everything to a matrix before running the function. If you want to use arbitrary functions across columns, then the more dplyr way to do that is with `rowwise()` and `c_across()`: `iris |> rowwise() |> mutate(SD=sd(c_across(-5)))`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! Recommendation very much appreciated. I have to study and practice this rowwise approach to get used to it. Old habits are hard to change ;-)